# Call a method on completion of save action on button click?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, commandbutton, oncomplete

I am trying to call a method on completion of action on buttonclick

Button Code:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" 
    id="saveButton" 
    status="actStatusId" 
    title="{!$Label.ahm__Save}" 
    value="{!$Label.ahm__Save}" 
    reRender="cREditPanel,pageMessagesPanel,pageMessages,campaignCRSection,eventCRSection"  
    oncomplete="completecallout();" 
    styleclass="ladda-button"/>
```

Controller: below method should be executed on complete of action in save button.

```
public void completecallout(){
    doCallout(selectedRecordId);
    system.debug('callout++'+selectedRecordId); 
}
```

on completion of save button action I need to execute the above method code.

Answer (score 1):

Oncomplete attribute accepts a JavaScript function.

You can use [action function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) or [JavaScript remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting.htm) if you want to call Apex function from JavaScript.

Visualforce code:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" 
    id="saveButton" 
    status="actStatusId" 
    title="{!$Label.ahm__Save}" 
    value="{!$Label.ahm__Save}" 
    reRender="cREditPanel,pageMessagesPanel,pageMessages,campaignCRSection,eventCRSection"  
    oncomplete="callCompleteCallout();" 
    styleclass="ladda-button"/>

<apex:actionFunction 
    name="callCompleteCallout" 
    action="{!completecallout}" 
    rerender="pageMessagesPanel"/>
```

Apex code:

```
public void completecallout(){
    doCallout(selectedRecordId);
    system.debug('callout++'+selectedRecordId); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need actionfucntion here. Call `onCompleteHandler` javascript method on `onComplete` of your commandbutton.

```
<script>
    function onCompleteHandler() {
         completecallout();
    }
</script>

<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" status="actStatusId" title="{!$Label.ahm__Save}" value="{!$Label.ahm__Save}" reRender="cREditPanel,pageMessagesPanel,pageMessages,campaignCRSection,eventCRSection"  oncomplete="onCompleteHandler();" styleclass="ladda-button"/>

<apex:actionfunction name="completecallout" action="{!completecallout}"/>
```